# Mudblazor datagrid add line break to CustomAggregate

Tags: mudblazor

is there a way to add line breaks or 
 to MudBlazor DataGrid CustomAggregate?

I've tried string interpolation method,  and just building a string variable.
The literal value is always shown in footer on datagrid

```
AggregateDefinition<OrderLineDTO> _totalExtAggregation = new AggregateDefinition<OrderLineDTO>
{
    Type = AggregateType.Custom,
    CustomAggregate = x =>
    {
        var totalGross = Convert.ToDecimal(x.Sum(z => (z.Qty * z.UnitPrice)));
        var totalDisc = Convert.ToDecimal(x.Sum(z => (z.Qty * z.UnitPrice)));
        string xx = totalGross.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + totalDisc.ToString();
        return xx;
        //return $"Total Gross: {totalGross.ToString("C2")} <br> Total Disc:    {totalDisc.ToString("C2")}";
    }
};
```